# How to run animation with joystick position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, joystick

This is my code...how to run animation with joystick position. if joystick full strectched then animation show fast. otherwise slow

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"walkcycle.plist"] ;

spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"walkcycle.png"];

[heroWorldLayer addChild:spriteSheet];

float frameInt = 33.0f;

CCArray *jumpFrames = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:33];
for(int i = 1; i <= 33; ++i) {
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Jump_Anim_V0200%02d.png", i]];
    [jumpFrames addObject:frame];
}
CCAnimation *jumpAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:[jumpFrames getNSArray] delay:1/frameInt];
CCFiniteTimeAction *jumpAnimate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:jumpAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
_jumpAction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:jumpAnimate times:1];


NSMutableArray *runFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 11; ++i) {
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Run_Anim00%02d.png", i]];
    [runFrames addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation *runAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:runFrames delay:1.0f/22.0f];
CCAnimate *runAnimate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:runAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
_runAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:runAnimate];


NSMutableArray *walkFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"walkcycle00%02d.png", i]];
    [walkFrames addObject:frame];
}

CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkFrames delay:(1-(controls.joyStickPos.x))/16.0f];
CCAnimate *walkAnimate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];
_walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:walkAnimate];


if (controls.joyStickPos.x < 0) {
    heroBodySprite.flipX = YES;

} else {
    heroBodySprite.flipX = NO;
}

if(controls.joyStickPos.x ==0){ // joystick pos
        if (_actionState != kActionStateWalk || _actionState == kActionStateIdle) {
            [heroBodySprite stopAllActions];
            [heroBodySprite runAction:_runAction];
            _actionState  = kActionStateWalk;
        } else {
            _actionState = kActionStateIdle;
        }
}
```

//my animation at joystick.pos.x == 0 otherwise it not show animation

```
if(controls.jmpBtn) { //joystick control jump
        if (_actionState != kActionStateJump || _actionState == kActionStateIdle) {
            [heroBodySprite stopAllActions];
            [heroBodySprite runAction:_jumpAction];
            _actionState = kActionStateJump;
        } else {
            _actionState = kActionStateIdle;
        }

        [self jump];
    }
when pressing only jump button no animation but if joystick and jump button move and press together then jump animation stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int current_state = 0; // at class implementation time

if ((controls.joyStickPos.x >= 0.7 || controls.joyStickPos.x <= -0.7) && current_state != 1){
    current_state = 1;
    [self runAnimation];
} else {

}

if (((controls.joyStickPos.x > 0 && controls.joyStickPos.x < 0.7) || (controls.joyStickPos.x < 0 && controls.joyStickPos.x > -0.7)) && current_state != 2){
    current_state = 2;
    [self walkAnimation];
} else {

}

if (controls.joyStickPos.x == 0 && current_state != 0) {
    [heroBodySprite stopAllActions];
    [wheelSprite stopAllActions];
    current_state = 0;
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out sneaky input which has joystick/D-Pad capabilities : [here](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput)
This does most of the work for you!

This is not the exact code, But it could be something like this

```
if (joystick.position.x <= joystick.position.x - 20) {
//Play slow animation
}
else {
//Play fast animation
}
```

Comment: You just need to do a couple tests, and determine the position of the joystick see my answer for an example